# Raw request Body Content

Tags: nancy

I'm developing Nancy web service that will collect data from clients which will send HTTP requests like this

```
POST /iclock/cdata?SN=3163602360001&table=OPERLOG&OpStamp=426433018 HTTP/1.1
Host: 218.108.223.49:9001
User-Agent: iClock Proxy/1.09
Connection: close
Content-Length: 4883
Accept: */*

OPLOG 0\tab 0\tab 2012-09-07 11:36:39\tab 0\tab 0\tab 0\tab 0
OPLOG 3\tab 0\tab 2012-09-07 11:36:42\tab 55\tab 0\tab 0\tab 0
```

Problem is, that I can't find a way to collect those data in Nancy module. Is there any way to get raw request body content inside Nancy module?

Comment: `var body = Request.Body.ToString();` if I remember correctly. Or it's `.AsString()`

Comment: `.AsString()` works like a charm :) Can you post your comment as answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `.AsString()` on the body tag to return the payload stream as the raw text passed from the client.

e.g

`var body = Request.Body.AsString();`

Comment: You have to include `using Nancy.Extensions;` to use this method.

Comment: In Nancy 2.0 it is now `var body = RequestStream.FromStream(Request.Body).AsString();` the extension requires a RequestStream. Request body is a steam.

Comment: @Jason you should put in the Nancy 2.0 solution as a separate answer IMO :)

Comment: Remember to set `Request.Body.Position = 0` if you have already read from the stream, if not you will get an empty string.

Answer (score 8):

For NancyFX 2.0 you will need to read the body as a stream.

`var body = RequestStream.FromStream(Request.Body).AsString();`

This then allows you to get the body as text.

Comment: And for anyone who needs the full qualification (for e.g. a quick look using the Immediate Window) this should do it: `Nancy.Extensions.RequestStreamExtensions.AsString(Nancy.IO.RequestStream.FromStream(nancyModule.Request.Body))` where `nancyModule` is a reference to your Nancy module (or `this` if you're in the module class).

Comment: NancyFX 2.0 has not been released yet, and there seems to be some doubt that it ever will be: https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/issues/2872